# How to implement sem_open using semget

Tags: c, linux, semaphore

I want to implement some POSIX semaphore APIs using System V semaphore and find this blog [Implement POSIX Semaphore APIs using System V Semaphores APIs](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-semaphore/index.html) useful.

I use `semget`(System V) to implement `sem_open`(POSIX). As follows:

```
sem_t *sem_open(const char *name, int oflag, ...) {
    creat(fname, 0444);
    key_t key = ftok(name, 1);
    semget(key, 1, IPC_CREAT)
}
```

But `semget` returns the **semaphore set** identifier while `sem_open` return a new POSIX semaphore. The number of allowed semaphore set is quite small, so I can't create many semaphores. How can I get rid of it.

Comment: Is there easy way to make `semget` call return a single semaphore rather than a semaphore set?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are asking about how to increase the limit on the system. In order to do that you can find current settings by running the following command on your Linux system (alternatively ipcs will work as well)

```
# cat /proc/sys/kernel/sem
250 32000   32  128
```

Now from the man pages we are looking at following four values from the above output

> SEMMSL
>
> - Maximum number of semaphores per semid: implementation dependent (on    Linux, this limit can be read and modified via the first field
>     of    /proc/sys/kernel/sem).
>
> SEMMNS
>
> - System wide maximum number of semaphores: policy dependent (on Linux,    this limit can be read and modified via the second field of 
>     /proc/sys/kernel/sem). Values greater than SEMMSL * SEMMNI makes it
>     irrelevant.
>
> SEMOPM
>   - maximum number of semaphore operations that can be performed per semop(2)
>
> SEMMNI
>
> - System wide maximum number of semaphore sets: policy dependent (on       Linux, this limit can be read and modified via the fourth field of
>     /proc/sys/kernel/sem).

Now in order to modify any one of the above kernel parameter you can run following command

```
# printf '250\t32000\t50\t150' >/proc/sys/kernel/sem
```

Comment: Oh, maybe I not say clearly. I wan't a correct implementation.

Comment: Perhaps if you can re-state specific problem you are running into. What are you trying to get rid of? or what specific problem are you trying to solve.